# angularjs show and hide ng-repeat elements with different index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to show the elements when the user clicks on a particular number and to have their own scope, I'm trying to reproduce the functionality available in this website's room selection dropdown **[room selection](https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels)**. Adding of rooms is limited to 5 and when the user adds a new room the same functionality should be applied to the added room with different scopes and I need to get their values after the user clicks done button. I have included the snippet of what I have done, please have a look. thanks
    **[JsFiffle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthikgirraj/xhg50bbu/)**

```
$scope.showOne = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        $scope.One = true;
        $scope.Two = false;
        $scope.Three = false;
        $scope.Four = false;
    }

    $scope.showTwo = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        $scope.One = true;
        $scope.Two = true;
        $scope.Three = false;
        $scope.Four = false;
    }

    $scope.showThree = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        $scope.One = true;
        $scope.Two = true;
        $scope.Three = true;
        $scope.Four = false;
    }

    $scope.showFour = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        $scope.One = true;
        $scope.Two = true;
        $scope.Three = true;
        $scope.Four = true;
    }
```

Comment: use an object and set properties of the object instead of using primitives.  This is one example of the rule you should always follow in angular: "**Always** use a dot in angular bindings".

Comment: sorry, here's the link [JsFillde](http://jsfiddle.net/karthikgirraj/xhg50bbu/1/)

Comment: Hi @Claies can you please be some more specific, or any reference will be fine

Comment: I tried making a few changes to your fiddle, but I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you are trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the functionality available in this website [rooms](https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels) have a look at this [image](http://pasteboard.co/2YFBDuj3z.png), thank you @Claies

Comment: sorry, I don't make a practice of studying other people's websites to try and reproduce their functionality.  You should **clearly describe the desired result** in the question body.

Comment: but just looking at that screenshot, you are really approaching this problem completely wrong.  You should consider having an array holding the occupants, and push elements into that array, then use `ng-repeat` to iterate the array.  having a bunch of functions with duplicate toggles is a mess.

Comment: ok, I'm able to show and hide the elements for the children tag for a specified value for lets say room1, when I add another room, I need a different scope with the same functionality, problem is for all the rooms, the adding and removing of child elements has the same scope and its showing/hiding(triggering) for all the rooms, I need to show/hide for a specific room with their own scope(please look into my jsfiddle),I have a hard time describing the functionality so I thought of giving a reference to understand it good, my apologies

Comment: right, so each room should be an array holding the occupants, correct?

Comment: yes, you are right